# Как в SQL присвоить DEFAULT значения в существующую таблицу?

Tags: база-данных

Я сейчас читаю книгу, но там про default используется при создании новой таблицы. А как сделать, чтобы, вот, уже существует таблица, и строки некоторые заполнены, допустим одна строка, а потом уже в остальные поместить DEFAULT значения в КОНКРЕТНЫЕ колонки??? И еще поместить в следующие 3 строки, например, в определенные колонки DEFAULT значения.

P.S Знаю что издевательство это над БД, но чтобы хорошо знать, нужно просочиться в детали (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изучайте ALTER TABLE для существующей таблицы.